# How to continuously read files by Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm a Kafka newbie.

I have tried some file reading examples and applied to my project for couple of weeks. However, my application does not seem to work as I wanted so I'm asking for your advise.

My intention is to :

1. Kafka producer reads files from directory A.
2. Storm consumes data that's been produced from 1.
3. Move away once read file to some other directory.

Condition :

1. Files are continuously sent into directory A.

It is a simple logic but it gives me headache.

So far I have created and tested Kafka producer code on my local computer eclipse.

What I thought is, because kafka producer should keep on reading files, the process has to be kept alive even if all the files in directory A are read. 
But instead it terminates as soon as all the files in directory A have been read and sent.

I run Kafka on a single node with 3 brokers, and the following is Producer properties setting.

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("producer.type", "sync");
props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
```

Topic has been created with the following command.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic test
```

Is my thought of continuously file reading wrong in Kafka's architectural perspective?
Or is there a way that I yet to find for?
I'd be very appreciated if someone can answer my problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `kafka.serializer.DefaultSerializer` (binary).
How are you monitoring folder for new files?
You could use something like `apache.commons.io.monitor`. Take a look [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/FileAlterationListener.html#line.64).

Where are you stuck? What are the problems you need to address (error messages, anything really)?
Asking because it looks like you want a complete solution from someone, which is not what SO provides. Dig in and ask specific questions, and of course, post the code.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! It was very helpful. I'll try to ask specific questions later on.

Answer (score 0):

By Using Kafka Connect

```
#File connect-standalone.properties

#bootstrap kafka servers
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# local file storing offsets and config data
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=C:\\KafkaSetup\\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\\libs

# File myFileConnector.properties 
name=local-file-source
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
file=C:\\KafkaSetup\\input\\data.txt
topic=aryan_topic

#Command
C:\KafkaSetup\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\bin\windows>connect-standalone.bat C:\\KafkaSetup\\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\\config\\connect-standalone.properties C:\\KafkaSetup\\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\\config\\myFileConnector.properties 

#data.txt contains
Hello By Arun

#Kafka client
C:\KafkaSetup\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9094 --topic aryan_topic
i]3
gh
"Hello By Arun"
```